# Can't load google chrome driver in selenium java on linux

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, selenium

I've started using selenium over java in eclipse on linux (CentOS 6.6).

With Firefox everything works fine but with Chrome I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'localhost.localdomain', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at First.testGoogleSearch(First.java:24)
    at First.main(First.java:18)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'localhost.localdomain', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:13244/status] to be available after 20001 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:175)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:80)
```

What I've tried:

1. Changing the SetProperty to path to real path instead of symlink.
   That's following additional stack-overflow posts on the issue which suggested the above.
2. Installing a higher version of Java (using 1.7, installed 1.8).

That's my code, help would be appreciated:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;


public class First {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        testGoogleSearch();
    }
    public static void testGoogleSearch() throws InterruptedException {
      //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "//home//shai//selenium//chromedriver");    
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "//etc//alternatives//google-chrome");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("http://some url");
      driver.quit();
    }


}
```

Comment: what is your chrome driver & browser version

Answer (score 0):

There are various possibilities for this issue to occured.

Please check the chromedriver is whether 32 bit or 64 bit. It must match with your OS.

**OR**

It might be the because of folder permission. Please give execute permission to the folder where chromedriver is located.

Comment: OS and Driver is 64 bit (tried with 32 just in case). Folder has execute permission